# Using the Bitnami WordPress helm chart, how can I connect Filezilla via FTP?

Tags: kubernetes, ftp, sftp, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I'm trying to connect to a Bitnami WordPress Helm release via FileZilla but I don't know how I would go about it.

I'm not sure where to get the ftp credentials, etc.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bitnami WordPress container images does not have ftp/ssh enabled, so it is not possible to connect via FileZilla.
However, as it is a kubernetes deployment, you can use `kubectl exec -it name_of_the_wordpress_pod bash` and get into the running pod and perform the actions you need. If you want to copy files, then use `kubectl cp`.